# How to find which library exports a function?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, clang

For instance I have a program that reports `undefined reference to 'XRenderFindVisualFormat'`

Can I use something like a combination of find/grep/file ?

Comment: It is probably the compiler (actually the linker) which gives that message.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nm` (or `nm -D`) on a library do get the symbols defined or used there. See [nm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html) and also [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html).

You can use `ldd` on some executable to understand which shared dynamic libraries it is linking. See [ldd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html).

You can also search the web for `XRenderFindVisualFormat`

Remember that order of libraries and program options to `gcc`  is significant.